# Quick Sort Implementation Attempt

Tags: java, quicksort

I attempted to write a quicksort implementation after watching this video on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZaf_9IZCrc&t=215s but it does not work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you
Ferda

```
 public class Trial{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int arr[] = {7, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5};
        quickSort(arr, 0, 6);
     }


     public static void quickSort(int[] arrInput, int start, int end){

         int arr[] = new int[end-start+1];
         for(int i=start, j=0; i<end; i++, j++){
             arr[j]=arrInput[i];
         }
         int size = arr.length;
         int pivotValue = arr[size-1];

         for (int i=-1; i<arr.length; i++){
           for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
            if(arr[j]< pivotValue){
                int temp = arr[j];
                i++;
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
            for(int p = i; p< size-2; p++ ){
                arr[p+1] = arr[p];
            }
            arr[i] = pivotValue;
            quickSort(arr, 0, i);
            quickSort(arr, i+1, size-1);
           }
         }

      }
}
```

Comment: the quicksort algorithm is composed by three part, one part called partition and thow others part they are two recursive call to two part of partitionned array

Comment: the video you see speack about partition of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicksort is something like that:

```
public static void quicksort(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
    if (array == null || array.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    int pivot = partition(array);
    quicksort(array, 0, pivot);
    quicksort(array, pivot + 1, array.length);
}

public static void quicksort(int[] array) {
    quicksort(array, 0, array.length());
}
```

After that, you can use your video to implement partition method

Answer (score 0):

Video which you mentioned here, tells about partition mechanism.So elements with value less than pivot come before the pivot, elements value greater than pivot come after pivot(equal can go either way).There are two parts if quick sort algorithms, `partition` and `quicksort` . Quicksort is `in place sort`, and you do not need to create new array here. And you chose last element as pivot element, you can follow below given pseudo code to implement quicksort:

```
quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
if lo < hi then
    p := partition(A, lo, hi)
    quicksort(A, lo, p – 1)
    quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)



partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[hi]
    i := lo     // place for swapping
    for j := lo to hi – 1 do
        if A[j] ≤ pivot then
            swap A[i] with A[j]           
            i := i + 1
swap A[i] with A[hi]
return i
```

Comment: Thanks I will try to fix the problems in my implementation according to this :)

Comment: Hi, Bhagwati can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problem causes me not entering new questions.

Comment: @Ferda-Ozdemir-Sonmez Done.